# React Grid Side-bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a react css grid where the "side panel" always shows.
I'm new to react and a little confused with how to stack things.

Code:

```
return (
\<div\>
\<Aside /\>
\<Header /\>
\<Hero /\>
\<Middle /\>
\<End /\>
\<Footer /\>
\</div\>
);
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0;
position: relative;
background-color: beige;



display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;

grid-template-areas:
"aside header header header"
"aside hero hero hero"
"aside middle-display middle-display middle-display"
"aside end-display end-display end-display"
"aside footer footer footer";

gap: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%; }
```

I tried wrapping it into a section, different divs and more still not getting ideal result.

[Here is my result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sxiK.jpg)
[This is what i'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abUNd.jpg)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This code achieves the structure that you want:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: beige;

  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas:
    "aside header header header header"
    "aside hero hero hero hero"
    "aside middle middle middle middle"
    "aside end end end end"
    "aside footer footer footer footer";

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

aside {
  background: grey;
  grid-area: aside;
}

header {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: header;
}


.section-one {
  background: red;
  grid-area: middle;
}

.section-two {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: end;
}

footer {
  background: royalblue;
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<aside>Aside</aside>
<header>Header</header>
<section class="section-one">Section1</section>
<section class="section-two">Section2</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```